# Создать из нескольких jpeg одно изображение на С++

Tags: c++, изображения

В буферах std::string хранятся присылаемые клиентами кадр с вебкамер в формате jpeg. При запросе просмотра нескольких камер на одной странице браузер сильно грузит процессор, обрабатывая с 20 камер. Хочу попробовать формировать на сервере одно изображение из нескольких камер, разбивая их чёрными полосками в пару пикселей, типа такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Только не знаю с чего начать...
С ресайзом вроде разобрался, но вот как их склеить в буфере в одну картинку не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это делается?

*PS: вебсокет-сервер на С++.*

Comment: Смотрите в сторону ImageMagick/GraphickMagick. Там все достаточно просто.

Comment: Думал libgd собрать, но что-то не выходит с msys

Comment: @KoVadim, ImageMagick - make: ***[all] Error 2 ... Как я "люблю" все эти библиотеки ))

Comment: Для этого прийдётся разпаковать в любой (RGB и т п) bmp-образный формат - собрать в один - упаковать jpg. Иначе не выйдет.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Хорошо, алгоритм jpeg-to-RGB и обратный имеются.Получается нужно просто сложить несколько RGB c добавлением чёрных пикселей в нужных местах?

Comment: Да. чёрный - нули (рисуется один раз). Один раз области наполнить нулями и всё. Копировать в один - построчно memcpy. Можно вместо RGB за 2 этапом использовать YCbCr https://habrahabr.ru/post/102521/ тогда на два преобразования меньше (YCbCr-RGB и RGB-YCbCr) - выигрыш в скорости.

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо за советы, теперь реализация задачи ясна! Буду собирать удобный класс из всех собранных в сети и написанных алгоритмов...

Comment: Ну и как послесловие - Формат flv (поддерживается браузерами) позволяет обвернуть jpg в поток. Но я это сам делать не пробовал. Cпецификацию где-то находил. Т.е. можно отдать заголовок, а потом пачками отдавать по-кадру шапка кадра + jpg потроха.